# How to transmit pointer to dynamically allocated array as a function parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to allocate an array inside of a function and to be able to use the pointer to that array outside of it as well. I don't know what's wrong with my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alloc_array (int **v, int n)
{
    *v=(int *)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    printf ("the address of the array is %p",v);
}

void display_pointer (int *v)
{
    printf ("\n%p",v);
}

int main()
{
    int *v;
    alloc_array(&v,3);
    display_pointer(v);

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect to get the same address in both `printf`s, but that is not the case. What is my mistake?

Comment: `printf ("the address of the array is %p",v);` ---> `printf ("the address of the array is %p",*v);` Recall what the double pointer is pointing to, and what its value is.

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you. I understand now. I actually feel pretty stupid for not realising this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void alloc_array (int **v, int n)
{
    *v = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    printf("the address of the array is %p", *v);
    //                                   ----^
}
```

Note the additional star in my `printf` call.

Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc` / `calloc`.

Comment: You are right. My bad for asking such an obvious thing, I didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make when you are dealing with multiple levels of indirection.

Comment: Could you please explain why the return value shouldn't be casted? I was taught that we should do this because those functions return a type void pointer

Comment: In C, `void*` can be freely assigned to pointers of other types without cast and vice-versa.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I understand. So casting it is just superfluous, or is it bad practice as well?
edit: thank you for the link, I am going to look into that

Answer (score 1):

`v` in `alloc_array` contains address of a pointer variable. That variable is `v`in `main()`.

You don't care about it. Because it won't change. But it the content of `v` in `main` would.

You should print `*v` but why?

Because the content of `v` in `alloc_array` contains the address of the memory that you allocated.

But `display_pointer` doesn't need this. because here you pass the pointer variable itself and the local copy of it in the *called* function will contain the address of the memory that you allocated.

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet

```
int *v;
alloc_array(&v,3);
display_pointer(v);
```

the function `alloc_array` accepts the address of the variable (pointer) `v` and this address is outputted in the function

```
printf ("the address of the array is %p",v);
```

On the other hand the function `display_pointer` accepts the value stored in the variable `v` and this value is outputted within the function

```
printf ("\n%p",v);
```

Add one more statement in the function `alloc_array` and you will see the difference

```
printf ("the address of the original pointer is %p", ( void * )v);
printf ("the address of the first element of the allocated array is %p", ( void * )*v);
```